# /usr/bin/ld: build-debug/obj/gpsitem.o: file not recognized: file truncated

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gcc, raspberry-pi

I'm using QT to build/run and i'm getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: build-debug/obj/gpsitem.o: file not recognized: file truncated

/usr/bin/ld: build-debug/obj/gpsitem.o: file not recognized: file truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:1703: debug/apmplanner2] Error 1
21:34:14: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project apm_planner (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
21:34:16: Elapsed time: 1:48:02.
```

anybody ideas why this is happening?

```
QT Creator 4.8.2
Based on QT 5.11.3 (GCC 8.3.0, 32 bit)
amhf raspberry pi
```

Update:
Clean build directory, new error

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.11.3/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Qt-5.11.3/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Qt-5.11.3/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:70925: build-debug/ui/ui_mapripform.h] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:70929: build-debug/ui/ui_MainWindow.h] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:70933: build-debug/ui/ui_CommSettings.h] Error 127
/usr/local/Qt-5.11.3/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:70937: build-debug/ui/ui_SerialSettings.h] Error 127
18:04:19: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project apm_planner (kit: Desktop)
When executing step "Make"
18:04:19: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

How to get libicui18n.so.57 ?

Comment: Possible corrupt file?

Comment: Maybe a build failed (compiler crash or somebody stopping a build midway) which left a corrupt file around. Try wiping your build directory and start over with a clean build from scratch.

Comment: Clean build directory, error changed to /usr/local/Qt-5.11.3/bin/uic: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.57: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: installing libicui fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

Installing libicui57 fixed this issue